# Can't parse GET request using express

Tags: node.js, express, get, httprequest, static-files

I read a lot about node, express and many useful modules. 
I'm trying to parse GET HTTP request but I'm doing something wrong.

Maybe this problem could be solved using `express.Router()` and `views engine` but I would like to know **WHY** this code doesn't work?

> Server is up and running! Public files are very well served **BUT** I cannot parse GET request.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/*I would like to get req.session here*/
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('I'm trying to log this string');
})
```

I'm also using **morgan** to log all HTTP request and this is the output:

```
Listening at: http://localhost:8080
GET / 200 14.288 ms - 9139
GET /css/materialize.css 304 16.311 ms - -
GET /css/style.css 304 24.775 ms - -
GET /js/materialize.js 304 21.287 ms - -
GET /js/init.js 304 20.238 ms - -
GET /js/index.js 200 51.159 ms - 2719
GET /fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2 304 2.419 ms - -
GET /fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2 304 3.663 ms - -
GET /fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2 304 7.958 ms - -
GET /fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2 304 9.010 ms - -
```

---

> It **works** commenting :

```
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

But, obviously, no file are served.

### Thank you!

PS: I never seen tutorial or code snippet explaining the situation described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a file called `index.html` in the `public/` directory, which is the one that will get served when requesting `/`, because that's what `express.static()` does by default.

You can disable that behaviour, so the request will be passed to your `/` handler:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { index : false }));
```

This is documented [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).

Alternatively, you can make sure that the request hits the `/` handler by declaring it *before* the static middleware:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('I'm trying to log this string');
  // make sure to end the response, to prevent hanging requests.
  res.end();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Hi Robert, yes, I have **index.html** into **public** folder. You totally understand the problem and I solved it declaring the get before static middleware, **but** with a little edit, using **next()** instead **res.end()**.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep), I solved doing this :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('I'm trying to log this string');
  // make sure to end the response, to prevent hanging requests.
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```